Build operation failed. Could not create several tasks
I get the following error message when trying to build an app.
A build operation failed.
Could not create task ':app:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac'.
Could not create task ':app:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac'.
Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac' property 'javaCompiler'.
Cannot find a Java installation on your machine matching this tasks requirements: {languageVersion=17, vendor=ADOPTIUM, implementation=vendor-specific} for MAC_OS on     aarch64.
No locally installed toolchains match and toolchain download repositories have not been configured.

I have the following code in my build.gradle:
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
        vendor = JvmVendorSpec.ADOPTIUM // Or use JvmVendorSpec.TEMURIN
    }
}

Checking terminal I have the newest java version:
openjdk version "17.0.13" 2024-10-15

your error message is quite helpful - requesting vendor ADOPTIUM but providing vendor OPENJDK (see also https://dzone.com/articles/an-overview-on-jdk-vendors)

change JvmVendorSpec.ADOPTIUM to JvmVendorSpec.ADOPTOPENJDK, see https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/jvm/toolchain/JvmVendorSpec.html

After cloning a repo and trying to build it for the first time I got the same error.
Check which JDK is your gradle using from:

Android Studio -> Settings -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Gradle JDK

then check what is required from your build.gradle in:
java {
  toolchain {

  }
}

Those two need to "match".
// For my personal case I just removed the java.toolchain block from my gradle entirely and it had no problem with the builds

I ended up removing the java.toolchain block myself to fix this issue
